# Git post-receive hook doesn't work with Github

Tags: wordpress, bash, git, githooks, git-post-receive

## Background and Setup

I'm trying to follow [the last part of this tutorial here](https://tqdev.com/2018-deploying-with-git-push-to-production) to create a post-receive Git hook (really just an example, the instructions everywhere else are basically identical).

As well as my local repository, I have a GitHub repo set up as a remote called *central*, and a production server set up as a remote called *live*. 
I have everything in place such that I'm able to easily push from the local repository to GitHub, and SSH into the production server to pull from GitHub.

## The Goal

I want to do away with the latter step entirely, so that all I need to do is push to the central repository, from where the production server will pull those changes automatically - and everything I've seen tells me a post-receive hook is the way to do this.

## The Problem

For some reason, everything I've tried so far to get the post-receive hook to work has failed.

My `post-receive` file exists on my production server in `.git/hooks/`, it's been made executable with `chmod ug+x`, and yes, "post-receive" is spelt right. The `post-receive` file contains the following Bash code:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/www.example.com/public_html || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull central master
exec git update-server-info
```

I can even SSH into the production server and execute the `post-receive` hook manually, and yet for some reason it isn't triggered when I push to the central repository, *despite* the fact that all the guides specify this is the way it should work.

The single way that I've diverged from these guides is that the repository on my server is a non-bare one, but from what I've learnt of the differences between the two this shouldn't make a difference where it's already been established that I can push and pull as normal.

So why exactly is my post-receive hook not working?

### Edit: Test 1

Changing the `cd` line to:

```
cd ~/www.example.com/public_html && touch ./cd_ran_successfully || exit
```

...and then doing the push command locally results in no `cd_ran_successfully` file being created on the server. However, manually executing the file when logged into the server, does create the file. This indicates some sort of problem with the user/process that the shared server is using to execute the file, but other than that I have no idea.

Comment: most likely it dies at the first line. does the server run under your account? is `~` expanded correctly?

Comment: @Serge The server is a Siteground shared server, I have a user on it but no root access. You were right about it dying at the first line, see the edit.

Comment: Can you clarify some things?  Are you hosting your own GitHub server?  The post-receive hook needs to be set for the repo that is being pushed to -- from the way you worded your question that is the GitHub repo.  GitHub does not allow custom hooks so unless you're hosting an enterprise GitHub you will not be able to do this.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, I'm using Github as the central repository into which I want to push and pull all my code. Are you saying that you can't use Git hooks with Github? That does make sense; now that I think about it, none of the articles or questions on it specifically dealt with using Github, I suppose I may have confused Git itself with Github in that respect. I have heard of Github's Webhooks, accessible via the website's GUI, so maybe they were designed to be the solution for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post-receive hook is a server-side hook, it needs to be on your git server.

Generally, to run custom hooks you will need to host your own git server.  From what it sounds like what you want, you need to setup your production server to also host a git server that you can set up as a different git remote that you can push to.

Then you can setup your post-receive to deploy the files as needed.

Alternatively, you can setup a pre-push script to let your prod server know an update is available, albeit it is pretty hacky.

pre-push:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh user@prod "/home/user/my_script.sh &"
```

my_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Wait for push to go through
sleep(25)

cd git_dir && git pull

# Deploy
cp git_dir/binary /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware hosting a Git server was even an option. Would it be possible on a shared Siteground server with no root access?

Comment: Probably not, but you can always try.  I believe gitlab has a free personal option that you can look into.

Comment: The post receive hook will only fire on the git server you push to.  However you can always use the pre-push hook on your dev machine to send an ssh command to your server that a pull is available.  I can edit my answer.

Comment: To clarify, what is the difference between having Git installed on a server as I have (albeit a Siteground shared server), and hosting your own Git server? Or in other words, what makes a Git server a Git server?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by jpsalm, Git hooks can only be run on a Git server, which generally isn't common practice to set up when hosting websites and CMSes like Wordpress, especially on shared servers where root access is less likely. Instead of Git's hooks, Github implements its own version of a technology known as [webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook).

*N.B. Everything I've learnt below is the result of my research in the last few hours or so, and this answer is primarily for the purpose of consolidating this knowledge and making me feel like that time wasn't entirely wasted.*

Webhooks are a very similar technology to APIs - where an API functions to provide data that is requested by a user, webhooks seem to work in the inverse way: they listen for specified changes on the server and notify the user of those changes.

As commonly applied to Git and Github, a webhook listens to Github for an event, such as `git push`, and then sends a POST request containing all the details of that event to an *endpoint*. This endpoint is a script on the server written to parse the JSON from the POST request, check for authentication, and then execute another script on the server that actually does something - most commonly, pulling from the GitHub repo.

Github takes some of the pain of Webhooks out of the way by providing a web interface to create the request, but that still leaves the endpoint itself (what Github confusingly calls the payload, which I still don't get) to be programmed, in addition to the script that the endpoint will runs.

Unfortunately, I don't have the skill nr the time to write an endpoint for parsing JSON with Bash, or any other language for that matter, so until someone comes along and does just that, it looks like I'll have to settle for doing one extra `push` command. :)

Comment: One more thing I think will work for you -- bypass git entirely with a pre-push hook.  Modify the example pre-push I listed above to just scp -r your git repo to your production server and then run your update script remotely from the pre-push hook.